# How to set default value for a select in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

Regarding the following code:

```
<div class="slds-select_container" title={line.record.Order_Line_Status__c}>
    <select class="slds-select" value={line.record.Order_Line_Status__c}>
        <option value ="Awaiting Invoice">Awaiting Invoice</option>
        <option value ="Invoiced/Awating Payment">Invoiced/Awating Payment</option>
        <option value="Payment Received">Payment Received</option>
        <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

lwc doesn't allow me to set the value attribute on select, like react does. So I am wondering how should I be setting a default value on a select in lwc?